# how to access child class value in parent class (in different file) in python

Tags: python, class, oop

My parent class in(class1.py)

```
import class2
from class2 import *
class Parent:        # define parent class
   parentAttr = 100
   def __init__(self):
      print "Calling parent constructor"

   def parentMethod(self):
      print 'Calling parent method'

   def setAttr(self, attr):
      Parent.parentAttr = attr

   def getAttr(self):
      print "Parent attribute :", Parent.parentAttr
```

My child class in (class2.py)

```
import class1
from class1 import Parent
class Child(Parent): # define child class
    XYZ=100
    def __init__(self):
        print "Calling child constructor"

    def childMethod(self):
        print 'Calling child method'
```

i want to use variable XYZ in parent class.And also want to make child class instance in parent class file(class1.py).Can anybody help me how to do that?

Comment: 1. Make it parent's class variable. 2. Copy paste from class2.py to class1.py, skipping imports.

Comment: That would be a circular dependency. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: Are you sure that you've understood object oriented programming?

Comment: yup i ll do that .but can you teach me how to make child class instance in parent class??please

Comment: There is probably something wrong in your design.

Comment: As you can easily derive from the comments, you are puzzling us, for we can't think of someone doing something so ... *searching for a polite synonym of stupid* ... weird! Please explain at least the reasoning of doing that, before asking someone to assist in logical sepuku.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
import class2
```

from **class1.py** and put the XYZ variable in class1.

Besides I recommend you to use composition over inheritance always you can. If you want be able to know something about child class, add the corresponding method to the interface.

Also should read: ["Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAB&url=http://dl.e-book-free.com/2013/07/head_first_object-oriented_analysis_and_design.pdf&ei=G1OwUoGfBInzoATQ8ICoCw&usg=AFQjCNHDOYZcd-hGqydgxYD4eTtBzGQHeA&bvm=bv.57967247,d.cGU)

Comment: And Liskov's substitution principle! For the sake of argument: if he's trying to do something like a Linked List, or Tree he should treat the objects (like leaf and node/branch) more as extensions to the base then as replacements!